# display jquery rules/validator error messages within the DIV tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image]I have couple of fields in DIV tags. These fields are validated using jquery rules/validator and when validation error occurs it displays the error message to the right inline with the input field which is in a DIV tag. the issue is when the rules validator shows error message which is relatively lengthier then the error message moves to the next line which pushes the next div tag to the bottom and it does this only to the form input field to the right and not to the label on the left which is also a DIV. so the label and input fields gets mis-aligned. attached image has the fields misaliged.

Fields pseudo,

```
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Location:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:select path="location" items="${locationList}" itemValue="code" itemLabel="desc" /></DIV>
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Reference Transaction Number:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:input path="refTranNbr" maxlength="20" size="20" /></DIV>
<DIV class="outer-left-bm">Date of Reference Transaction:&nbsp;</DIV><DIV class="outer-right-bm"><form:input path="refTranDate" size="10" maxlength="10" /> (mm/dd/yyyy)</DIV>
```

Jquery rules/validator messages

```
$("#aFormID").validate({
        rules: {            
            refTranNbr: {
                required:  function (element) {
                    return $("#refTranDate").val().length > 0;
                },
                refNumChk: true
            },
            refTranDate: {
                required:  function (element) {                 
                    return $("#refTranNbr").val().length > 0;
                },
                lessThanToday: true
            },
            messages: {         
                    refTranNbr: {
                        required: "Please enter the reference transaction number to complete this transaction.",        
                        refNumChk: "Please enter a valid Reference Transaction Number.  Note: All letters must be in upper case."
                    },          
                    refTranDate: {
                        required : "Please enter a date for the Refering Transaction to complete this transaction.",
                        lessThanToday: "Please enter a reference transaction date less than today's date."
            }
            }

    });
```

Corresponding CSS:

```
DIV.outer-left-bm {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
DIV.outer-right-bm {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
label.error {
    /* remove the next line when you have trouble in IE6 with labels in list */
    color: red; 
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-style: italic;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

Comment: You can hardcode div's height , cut too long text and add a title to div that will show full text of message. This way acceptable?

Comment: Adding title to DIV to show full text? Can you explain with example please.

Comment: Check this:

    <div style = "width:100px; height:100px; color:red" title = "This text will be shown when you move mouse pointer over this div">Short text</div>

Comment: This DIV gets displayed only when there is a error message? So Should i wrap this up within error label?

Comment: Doesn`t matter, title is bubbleable. You even can change your messages like:
   


                        required: "<span title = 'Please enter the reference transaction number to complete this transaction.'>Requires number</span>",

Comment: Looks like i cannot cut short the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can add parent div which will combine both the `<div>` with `.outer-left-bm` and `.outer-right-bm`, say parent `<div>`.

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="outer-left-bm">Reference Transaction Number:&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="outer-right-bm"><form:input path="refTranNbr" maxlength="20" size="20" /></div>
</div>
```

And add the following CSS to the parent `<div>`:

```
.parent {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: No it doesnt align properly. Just copied your code and corresponding CSS.